# Server name SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have installed SQL Server 2005 Express with Management Studio Express; but it doesn't accept my server name.

- I checked its help and found out that server name is my PC  `name\sqlexpress`.
- I have changed my PC name from inside 'my computer' properties window.
- I am running winxp professional.
- I also tried '.'

Your help will be appreiated

Comment: How do you know it doesn't accept your server name? Does it output an error by any chance?

Comment: `.\sqlexpress` should allow you to connect. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed SQL Server Express with all defaults, then the instance should be called `SQLEXPRESS` and thus these machine names *should* work:

- `.\SQLEXRPESS`
- `(local)\SQLEXRPESS`
- `MachineName\SQLEXRPESS`

Note: you had `sqlexress` (missing the `p`) in your original post - I fixed this, but if you really try `sqlexress` - then OF COURSE it didn't work :-)

Comment: It didn't work.So something else should be wrong.What's it then

Comment: @Soheil1: so in that case, you *most likely* installed SQL Server Express and chose a **non-standard** instance name - use that **instance name** to connect - `(local)\YOURINSTANCENAMEHERE`

Comment: I  have downloaded&installed Management Studio Express.I wonder  if I should download anything else...........

Comment: @Soheil1: if you **only** installed Management Studio - then you **don't have the engine!** Of course you cannot connect to it..... you need to download **SQL Server Express** (the actual database engine - standalone, or *with Tools* or *with Advanced Services*) ....